# Using pictures / images as x-axis label in pgfplot?

Tags: pgfplots, graphics, labels

is it somehow possible to use external pictures as explicit labels in `pgfplot`?
Or can I use the draw environment within the label definition?

I tried it in two ways:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={Motifs},
ylabel={Value},
xtick={1,2},
xticklabels={%
    \draw (0,0) node {} -- (2,4) node {} -- (4,0) node {};, %
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,xscale=0.2,yscale=0.2]%
    \draw (0,0) node {} -- (2,4) node {} -- (4,0) node {} -- (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
]
\addplot+
table[x=motif,y=original] 
{
    motif   target  original    reached 
    2   0.0 0.36755204594400576 0.0 
    1   1.0 0.6324479540559943  1.0 
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result should look like this

[image: pgfplot with images as xaxis labels]

Thanks in advance for any hints or tips!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
 \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={Motifs},
ylabel={Value},
xtick={1,2},
xticklabels={\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{example-image-a},\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{example-image-b}
}
]
\addplot+
table[x=motif,y=original]
{
    motif   target  original    reached
    2   0.0 0.36755204594400576 0.0
    1   1.0 0.6324479540559943  1.0
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, that works. Stupid me, could have had this idea by myself .. 
I just made the pictures with QTikz and exported them as pdf to import them again within latex. Thanks!