# Plotting two 2D-plots in a 3D plot using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I am trying to create a 3D plot similar to a standard `xyz` coordinate system by using `pgfplots`. I want to plot two 2D plots one in `x1-y` and one in `x2-z` plane, similar to the following illustration (some of my x-labels are graphics similar to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237717), and I hope this does not limit me in what I am looking for).

[image]

How can I modify my code below to achieve this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
    a,b,c
    1,4,1
    2,3,2
    3,5,3
    4,1,4
    5,3,5
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [
            xlabel={$x_1$}, 
            xtick={1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
            xticklabels={\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{example-image-a},\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{example-image-b}, 3, 4, 5},
        ]
            \addplot+ table [x=a, y=b, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
        \end{axis}

        \begin{axis}[xlabel={$x_2$}]
            \addplot+ table [x=a, y=c, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\addplot3` to make a 3D-plot, and then set the either x or y to zero (depending on which plane you're in) with `x expr=0`/`y expr=0` as in the code below.

I also set `axis lines=center` and modified the `view`, to get something similar to your sketch.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
    a,b,c
    1,4,1
    2,3,2
    3,5,3
    4,1,4
    5,3,5
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [   
            axis lines=center,view={115}{45},
            xlabel={$x_1$}, ylabel=$x_2$,zlabel=$z$,
            xtick={1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
            xticklabels={\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{example-image-a},\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{example-image-b}, 3, 4, 5},
        ]
            \addplot3+ table [y=a, z=b, x expr=0,col sep=comma] {data.csv};

            \addplot3+ table [x=a, z=c, y expr=0, col sep=comma] {data.csv};

            \begin{scope}[on background layer]
              \addplot3 [fill=blue!10,draw=none] coordinates {(0,0,5)(0,5,5)} \closedcycle;
              \addplot3 [fill=red!10,draw=none] coordinates {(0,0,5)(5,0,5)} \closedcycle;
            \end{scope}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Is it also possible to control the angle between the axes, e.g., to make it wider or narrower, or also changing the orientation of the `3D` plot?

Comment: @Ahmad Try playing with the `view`  parameters, e.g. `view={135}{15}`. The first number defines rotation around the z-axis, the second is the angle above the xy-plane. What do you mean by 'orientation of the plot'?

Comment: Please look at this picture for better illustration of what I mean by orientation: http://postimg.org/image/nr10vo67r/.

Comment: @Ahmad Can't you just swap `xlabel` and `ylabel`?

Comment: I wanted to have the plot `x2-y` plane exactly similar to a 2D plot, where `x2`-axis is perfectly horizontal and `y`-axis is perfectly vertical. With this, `x1` will be in an angle to this plane, similar to the plot in the right of this picture http://postimg.org/image/nr10vo67r/ or similar to the one I posted in my question above.

Comment: just a an addition if I may to Torbjørn T's solution, if you need curves - see the addition in the code below

Comment: @Ahmad I could be wrong, but I don't think that can be done with the above configuration, because the axes are orthogonal to each other.

Comment: @KKK To be brutally honest, this question isn't about plotting smooth curves, it's about the configuration of the axes, and in that sense your answer doesn't contribute anything new. So I for one won't be upvoting, sorry.

Comment: I would also really appreciate it, if you could also comment on how I can set a background color specifically for `x2-y` and `x1-y` planes.

Comment: @Ahmad Please try to include all your requirements in the question at once. Having to revisit accepted answers with new additions (that are somewhat unrelated to the original one) is actually a bit annoying. But see the updated answer. If you want a solution that doesn't require manually adding the numbers, ask a new question.

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
a,b,c
1,4,1
2,3,2
3,5,3
4,1,4
5,3,5
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    [   axis lines=center,view={125}{30},
        xlabel={$x_1$}, ylabel=$x_2$,zlabel=$z$,
        xtick={1, 2, 3, 4, 5},ymin=0,ymax=5,
        xticklabels={\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{example-image-a},\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{example-image-b}, 3, 4, 5},
    ]
        \addplot3+ table [y=a, z=b, x expr=0,col sep=comma] {data.csv};

        \addplot3+ [very thick, smooth] table [y=a, z=b, x expr=0,col sep=comma] {data.csv};% to plot curves

        \addplot3+ table [x=a, z=c, y expr=0, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{document}
```

[image: plots]